# What impact did the martyrdom of Iranian children have on the Iran-Iraq war?

Tags: iran, war-crime

> Iraq's extensive use of chemical weapons, and deliberate attacks on
> civilian targets.
> **A notable feature of the war was the state-sanctioned glorification of martyrdom among Iranian children;**  the discourses on martyrdom
> formulated in the Iranian Shia Islamic context led to the widespread
> usage of human wave attacks and thus had a lasting impact on the
> dynamics of the conflict. ([source1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War) [source2](https://iranwire.com/en/features/64724/))

Wikipedia mentions a "lasting impact". But what was it? Ideological? Strategic? Perhaps both?

Comment: Neither here, nor there, but child soldiers can make operational sense, albeit in a twisted and disgusting way:  by recruiting mostly indigenous teens, [Shining Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shining_Path) in Peru ensured that it would not be getting infiltrated by undercover cops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the discourses on martyrdom formulated in the Iranian Shia Islamic
> context led to the widespread usage of human wave attacks and thus had
> a lasting impact on the dynamics of the conflict.

For answering this question, we should take look at Iran's situation when the war began.The war began in 1980, less than two years after Iran's revolution. After the revolution, many high ranked army men in Iran were purged, so the army had become really weak, that's why Saddam decided to attack Iran.
Besides, the Islamic republic created another armed force, IRGC, so that the regular army wasn't the only armed force, IRGC became more powerful as the time passed by.But IRGC was not an ordinary army, it was a kind of religious army, its members were(and still are)brainwashed and fanaticized in order to do jihad and the best choice for such operations were children, between 12 to 17.
An example is [Hossein Fahmideh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Hossein_Fahmideh), a 13 year-old boy whose suicide attack against an Iraqi tank became a model for other children to do the same. I remember in our books at school we saw regularly  this quotation by Khomeini:

> Our hero is the boy who threw himself under the tank.

The *long lasting impact* is using  children in military operations, they sacrificed themself and opened the way for the rest of army and the regime represented them as hero and they became a model for other children to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The lasting impact was the glorification of martyrs as examples to society at large and paying of families of those who died in the pursuit of political gain. There's a [whole Wikipedia article on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrdom_in_Iran).

> To encourage volunteers, religious leaders broadened the definition of a martyr, announcing that all fatalities of the war [with Iraq] were to be considered martyrs for the country, and therefore for Islam.

The largest impact has been the funding and improved social status of the families of martyrs

> While the loss of a loved one is clearly a tragic and distressing event for a family, the families of martyrs in Iran were well taken care of. Having a martyr in the family meant immediate and permanent social mobility for many families. It was a mark of respect to have lost a son in the war, and the public displays honoring martyrs kept the memory of a family's loss alive in the community. Even beyond the social support of the community, the families of martyrs received certain tangible benefits. A large percentage of spots in many schools were reserved for the children of martyrs and having a martyr in the family gave a job applicant an edge against other applicants. Families of war martyrs were given certificates of martyrdom at the event of their child's death which gave them discounts for groceries and clothes. Societies were set up for the sole purpose of helping the families martyrs or the "living martyrs" who were injured during the Iran/Iraq War.

This idea of funding martyrs has been exported to other areas under Iran's influence, where it has taken on a new dimension. Hamas and Fatah, for instance, [both fund the families of martyrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_Authority_Martyrs_Fund)

> The Palestinian Authority Martyrs Fund is a fund operated by the Palestinian Authority (PA) that pays monthly cash stipends to the families of Palestinians killed, injured, or imprisoned while carrying out politically motivated violence against Israel.

In particular, they fund suicide bombers

> Hamas has operated a separate fund for years predating before its takeover of the Gaza Strip in 2007. In 2001, Sheikh Ahmed Yassin, the founder of Hamas, boasted that Hamas payments to the families of prisoners and of suicide bombers totaled between $2 and $3 million. According to a 2001 report by the Israeli government, the families of prisoners received an initial lump sum payment of between $500 and $5,000, with monthly stipends of about $100, with higher payments for the families of Hamas members.

In short, by paying people to kill themselves and take as many political enemies with them, Iran has created a new type of war with people (who are often in desperate financial circumstances) turning themselves into expendable weapons for the sake of their families.

Comment: that's highly unusual. now i wonder what happens if some kid decides he doesn't want to become a martyr and rather quit or run away, or a suicide bomber who at the last minute decides to ask for help and not detonate? will it be disgrace for the family? repercussions? and how they even recruit? do they go to elementary schools?

Comment: @ForShaniNicoleLouk The Oscar-nominated Palestinian film "Paradise Now" gives a real feel for the conditions and how it works.